# Using a POJO as an iReport data source

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a POJO that compiles data from various sources into a single object. The object is instantiated with a single parameter. Example:

```
Invoice inv=new Invoice(1239);
```

This will bring back a complete invoice containing other POJOs populated with data from various sources (such as the billing and shipping addresses as `Address` objects).

Can I use this as a data source within iReport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try use a `JRMapCollectionDataSource` from which you can build a DataSource from a collection.

You could take the values from the POJO object and place them into a collection if possible.

Here is some sample code for constructing a DataSource.

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> myColl = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map1.put("Field1","Value1");
map1.put("Field2","Value2");
map1.put("Field3", someObject);
myColl.add(map1);

JRMapCollectionDataSource source = new JRMapCollectionDataSource(myColl);
```

Another option would be to create a custom datasource by implementing `JRRewindableDataSource` or `JRDataSource`.